# Is there a way to cache python dictionaries locally, and make individual records expire periodically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, caching

I am making external API calls through a python script, and each response from a call is a JSON format dictionary.

The response from the API doesn't change all too often, possibly every 3 months or so. 
Ideally, what I would like to do is create a key-value pair, between the API parameter and the response.

I also do not want all records expiring, when clearing the cache, just a check to the cacheFile/localDatabase, for that parameter and then decide whether to delete that record.
If a value exists for that parameter, then see if that record has surpassed the "time to live", if it hasn't, then use that value, if it has, then use the API function to make that call and replace the value.
If the value doesn't exist, then make a new entry.

I would need to access this dictionary for my script, every time, to gather information about the parameter.

I tried pickles and pickle dump, but it seems, this is absolutely a poor idea, as it would clear the entire cache rather than the key that has expired.

Is there a link that can provide useful information, I am unsure whether I am searching the correct terms.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/08/12/a-tip-for-the-impatient-simple-caching-with-python-pickle-and-decorators/

I followed this tutorial, alhtough it offers a long term solution and a portable file, it may not be practical for the task at hand for two reasons:
1) clearing entire cache
2) Always returns the same result

Comment: please post your code: I tried pickles and pickle dump, but it seems, this is absolutely a poor idea, as it would clear the entire cache rather than the key that has expired.

Comment: one idea is to verify, at a certain period, used key and to update the value

Answer (score 0):

There is python library called `expiringdict` that seems like a good fit for your usecase.

You could create a cache something like below

```
from expiringdict import ExpiringDict
cache = ExpiringDict(max_len=100, max_age_seconds=180) # Three mins
# After 3 mins of inserting the key it will no longer exist in the dictionary
```

You could check if a key is present in the cache if it is present then you could use the value else it means that the key has expired and you need to make an API call.

```
if "key" in cache: # Will return false if 3 mins have surpassed
   return cache["key"]
else:
   value = #make api call and get value
   cache["key"] = value # Will store the value for 3 mins
   return value
```

Ref: https://pypi.org/project/expiringdict/